# How do I unit test an ASP.NET MVC controller that uses DotNetOpenId?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking, moq, dotnetopenauth

I have an **AccountController** whose constructor takes an object derived from my custom **IOpenIdAuthentication** interface. By default, this is an **OpenIdAuthenticationService** object that wraps an **OpenIdRelyingParty**. The interface looks like this:

```
public interface IOpenIdAuthentication {
    IAuthenticationResponse Response { get; }
    IAuthenticationRequest CreateRequest(string identifier);
}
```

I can mock **IAuthenticationResponse**:

```
_mockResponse = new Mock<IAuthenticationResponse>(MockBehavior.Loose);
_mockResponse.SetupGet(r => r.ClaimedIdentifier).Returns(identifier);
_mockResponse.SetupGet(r => r.Status)
    .Returns(AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated);
// ... removed the formatting of 'friendlyId' ...
_mockResponse.SetupGet(r => r.FriendlyIdentifierForDisplay).Returns(friendlyId);
```

However, I'm not sure how to mock **IAuthenticationRequest** as it appears much more complicated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not much more complicated. If you are doing only authentication, then mocking RedirectToProvider() would be enough. In the simplest case it looks like:

```
_mockRequest = new Mock<IAuthenticationRequest>(MockBehavior.Strict);
_mockRequest.Setup(r => r.RedirectToProvider());
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ah, thanks! I haven't used a mocking framework before, so I wasn't sure if I had to mock every part of the object.

Comment: If you are new to Moq then pay attention to difference between MockBehavior.Loose and MockBehavior.Strict. And there is a lot of automatic mocking features in the Moq library.